# How to echo time in format '2022-12-08T15:25:30.165965Z' in Linux bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Currently I am working on a bash script which has hardcoded the following date:

```
2022-12-08T15:25:30.165965Z
```

I would like to generate that date in the script and I would like it to be up to date. What I have tried so far is:

```
 date '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%M'
```

which outputs:

```
19-12-2022 12:40:13.40
```

I was wondering if someone knows how I could add the T and Z letters in the time?

Comment: The `T` and `Z` are literal characters, just like the spaces and `-`s. Just add them where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```bash
date -u '+%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.%NZ'
```

Here:

- `-u` will print UTC date-time
- `T` before `%H` will print literal `T`
- `%N` prints nanosecond value
- `Z` after `%N` will print literal `Z`

Comment: Hello! when I do `date -u '+%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.%NZ'` I get: `19-12-2022T11:46:51.NZ` So the nanos are not being calculated, do you maybe know why?

Comment: I suspect you don't have gnu date utility which is required to print nano seconds.

Comment: @marialadelbario why do you want nano-seconds anyway, they're really meaningless in regards to getting the current time as the time it takes to call `date` is longer than a nanosecond. If you're trying to call `date` in the order of every N nanoseconds than all you're really doing is slowing down whatever process you're running and if it's every N seconds then the nanoseconds are useless anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ date -u '+%FT%T.%6NZ'
2022-12-19T15:04:34.238733Z
```

You need GNU `date` for nanoseconds though.

Answer (score 1):

With just bash using the [EPOCHREALTIME](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-EPOCHREALTIME) variable and printf's `%(fmt)T` directive.

```bash
( IFS=.; TZ=UTC printf '%(%FT%T)T.%sZ\n' $EPOCHREALTIME )
# => 2022-12-19T14:28:33.343999Z
```

I'm using a subshell so that changing IFS does not affect the rest of the script.

Comment: You're right but it's for bash >= 5, +1

Comment: using `TZ=UTC printf '%(%FT%T)T.%sZ\n' "${EPOCHREALTIME%.*}" "${EPOCHREALTIME#*.}"` seems to be 5x fatser

Comment: The cost of launching a subshell I suppose.

Comment: There is a miniscule possibility that a new second could tick over between the 2 calls to EPOCHREALTIME so that "00:00:00.000001" is one second in the past